# How to inject Service Fabric service context into asp.net core middleware?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have a Service Fabric asp.net core stateless service which implements custom middleware. In that middleware I need access to my service instance. How would I go about injecting this using asp.net core's built-in DI/IoC system?

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        // ** need access to service instance here **
        return _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Someone mentioned accomplishing this using TinyIoC in Web Api 2 in the [Apr 20, 2017 Q&A #11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sqmxj9XpKDY) [45:30] with the Service Fabric team. As well that the current recommended method is to use asp.net core.

Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the asp.net core stateless service that creates the `ServiceInstanceListener` you can inject the context like this:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
                new WebListenerCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
                {
                    logger.LogStatelessServiceStartedListening<WebApi>(url);

                    return new WebHostBuilder().UseWebListener()
                                .ConfigureServices(
                                    services => services
                                        .AddSingleton(serviceContext) // HERE IT GOES!
                                        .AddSingleton(logger)
                                        .AddTransient<IServiceRemoting, ServiceRemoting>())
                                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                .UseUrls(url)
                                .Build();
                }))
        };
    }
```

Your middleware than can use it like this:

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, StatelessServiceContext serviceContext)
    {
        // ** need access to service instance here **
        return _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

For a complete example take a look at this repository: https://github.com/DeHeerSoftware/Azure-Service-Fabric-Logging-And-Monitoring

Points of interest for you:

- Setting up the DI: https://github.com/DeHeerSoftware/Azure-Service-Fabric-Logging-And-Monitoring/blob/master/src/WebApi/WebApi.cs
- Using context in middleware: https://github.com/DeHeerSoftware/Azure-Service-Fabric-Logging-And-Monitoring/blob/master/src/ServiceFabric.Logging/Middleware/RequestTrackingMiddleware.cs

Answer (score 1):

Dependency injection via constructor works for middleware classes as well as for others. Just add additional parameters to the middleware constructor

```
public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IMyService myService)
{
    _next = next;
    ... 
}
```

**But** also you can add dependency directly to the `Invoke` method

> [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware): Because middleware is constructed at app startup, not per-request, scoped lifetime services used by middleware constructors are not shared with other dependency-injected types during each request. If you must share a scoped service between your middleware and other types, add these services to the Invoke method's signature. The `Invoke` method can accept additional parameters that are populated by dependency injection.

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IMyScopedService svc)
    {
        svc.MyProperty = 1000;
        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I apologize, I wasn't clear on where my problem is... I understand asp.net core's DI model, my issue is more with how to get the Service Fabric service instance in my Startup.ConfigureServices to inject it.